# How to increase the sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity session duration

Tags: aws-sts, aws-roles

I have a user pool & respective identity pool(where auth role is provided with sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity).

I want the session duration to be more than 1 hour(i believe that is the default time).

How can i do that ?

I was able to increase the max session duration in the role, but is there any way to increase the session duration for sts.

I am very very very new to AWS, i am working with (monkey see monkey do) approach. Don't know the in's and Out of it.

Any help would be appreciated